# What happens to Government Bonds after the Central Bank buys them?

Tags: bonds, quantitative-easing

When a central bank buys its own government bonds if the government owns the central bank the government essentially owes money to itself. In this situation what is done with the Bonds?

Are they re sold later or destroyed? I don't think government cant pay itself yields on their own bonds so I assume they don't just hold onto them till they mature.

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/41252/37817 
  https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/52286/37817 
  https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/41873/37817 
  https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/6476/37817